# Function not updating variable as it goes through a while loop

Tags: c++, loops, variables, while-loop

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//resistivity ohms*meters
/*
 * 
 */
double diameter (double wiregauge)
{
  double k;
  double diam;

    k=((36-wiregauge)/39);
    diam=(.127)*(pow(92,k));
    diam=(diam/100);

  return diam;
}
double copperWireResistance(double length, double wiregauge)
{
    const long double PI=(atan(1)*4);
    int b; //equals k in the first function
    double diam1; //diameter of the wire
    double cross_area_copper; //denominator of the equation
    double numerator1; //numerator of the equation
    double p; //resistivity of copper
    double coppWireResistance;

    b=((36-wiregauge)/39);
    diam1=(.127*pow(92,b));
    diam1=(diam1/100);
    cross_area_copper=PI*(pow(diam1,2));
    p=(1.678*(pow(10,-8)));
    numerator1=((4*p)*length);

    coppWireResistance=numerator1/cross_area_copper;

        return coppWireResistance;

}

double aluminumWireResistance(double length, double wiregauge)
{
    const long double PI=(atan(1)*4);
    int a;
    double diam2;
    double numerator2;
    double cross_area_alum;
    double p1;
    double alumWireResistance;

    a=((36-wiregauge)/39);
    diam2=(.127*pow(92,a));
    diam2=(diam2/100);
    cross_area_alum=(PI*pow(diam2,2));
    p1=(2.82*pow(10,-8));
    numerator2=((4*p1)*length);

    alumWireResistance=numerator2/cross_area_alum;

        return alumWireResistance;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    double Max_N; //maximum wire gauge value
    double L; //Length of the wire
    double string_gauge=0;

    cout<<"Maximum wire gauge value: ";
    cin>>Max_N;
    cout<<"Length of Wire: ";
    cin>>L;


    while(string_gauge<Max_N)
    {
    cout<<"String Gauge: "<<string_gauge<<endl;
    cout<<"Diameter of wire: "<<diameter(string_gauge)<<endl;
    cout<<"Copper Wire Resistance: "<<copperWireResistance(L,string_gauge)<<endl;
    cout<<"Aluminum Wire Resistance: "<<aluminumWireResistance(L,string_gauge)<<endl;


    string_gauge++;
    cout<<endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Im trying to get the copperwireresistance and the aluminumwireresistance to update while it is running through a loop but after the first number it does not update to the new string gauge. Any reason or anything I need to add?

Comment: Please provide the important part not the whole program

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger? See [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: as i understand, your "Copper Wire Resistance" and "Aluminum Wire Resistance" don't change in any iterations, is it a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `wiregauge` parameter in each of the two functions is used for the following calculation:

```
a=((36-wiregauge)/39); // in aluminumWireResistance
b=((36-wiregauge)/39); // in copperWireResistance
```

Since `a` or `b` are `int` and that `wiregauge` is the only parameter that changes from a call to the other. `a` and `b` will always be equal to `0`. and the returned value of your function will always be the same.

To solve this issue and have more precision you can change the type of `a` to `double`.

Comment: Thank you, Im new to coding and it was a simple thing that I missed, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

`int a` kills your division in `a=((36-wiregauge)/39);`, and the rest is constant from there until you go negative.

Answer (score 0):

You have some troubles with `a` and `b` variables in your `copperWireResistance` and `aluminumWireResistance` functions. You declared them as int, but in your equation you gain a value, that less one.

Like a result, you always obtain same values, returned from functions.

So, change types to **float** or **double**.

ps. and change your `Max_N` type to **int** or **long**, if you compare your numbers with **<** operator.